# How to adjust sunplot height according to y-value of plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I would like to select the height of the subplots according to the maximum occurring y-value of the KDE plot (so that in the last subplot the whole KDE plot is still shown). 
Then how do I adjust the formula that draws the quartiles (ax[i-1].axvline(quatrilesx[k],.....])?
Why are these lines no longer visible at the moment?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter
import numpy as np
import random

def plotverweildauernwithuG(df):    

def rand_float_range(start, end):
    return random.random() * (end - start) + start



def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return idx


df=df[df['method']=='data']


df['years']=df['years'].astype('float64')



sns.set()
#sharex=True: x-Achse für alle Subplots geteilt
#fig,ax= plt.subplots(): tuple containing figure and axes object
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=df['cs'].max(), sharex=True)
nrows=len(ax)
ax[df['cs'].max()-1].set_xlabel('Verweildauer in Jahren')



s=[(df["cs"] == t).sum() for t in range(1, df['cs'].max()+1)]
s.insert(0, 0)
print(s)   


h=0
for i in range(1, df['cs'].max()+1):
    #get quartiles
    quatrilesx = [df[df['cs']==i]["years"].astype(float).describe()['25%'],df[df['cs']==i]["years"].astype(float).describe()['50%'], df[df['cs']==i]["years"].astype(float).describe()['75%']]
    verweildauer_i = df[df['cs'] == i]['years']

    cs_bandwith_i = df[df['cs'] == i]['cs_bandwith']
    color_i=df[df['cs'] == i]['uGW']

    verweildauer_i_nugw = df[(df['cs'] == i) & (df['uGW']==False)]['years']
    cs_bandwith_i_nugw = df[(df['cs'] == i) & (df['uGW']==False)]['cs_bandwith']

    verweildauer_i_ugw = df[(df['cs'] == i) & (df['uGW']==True)]['years']
    cs_bandwith_i_ugw = df[(df['cs'] == i) & (df['uGW']==True)]['cs_bandwith']


    #width=(10*nrows)/3
    #height=(7*nrows)/3
    #fig.set_size_inches(width,height)
    #plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)


    ax[i-1].scatter(verweildauer_i_nugw, cs_bandwith_i_nugw-i-0.5, c="blue", label = 'Verweildauer')
    ax[i-1].scatter(verweildauer_i_ugw, cs_bandwith_i_ugw-i-0.5, c="red", label = 'Unterer Grenzwert Verweildauer')  
    sns.kdeplot(verweildauer_i, ax=ax[i-1], shade=True, cumulative=False)
    #Get data points of Kde PLot
    data_x, data_y = ax[i-1].lines[0].get_data()

    if data_y.max()>h:
        h=data_y.max()

    width=(10*nrows)/3
    height=h
    fig.set_size_inches(width,height)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

    print(height)


    #Plot quartiles line
    for k in range(len(quatrilesx)):
        ax[i-1].axvline(quatrilesx[k], ymin=.3255, ymax=.3255+(height/width)*abs(data_y[find_nearest(data_x, quatrilesx[k])]), linestyle='dotted', color='black', linewidth=.6, alpha=.8)



    ax[i-1].set_ylim(-0.5,1)
    ax[i-1].set_ylabel('ZK ' + str(i))
    ax[i-1].set_yticks([])
    #draw the "y=0" line
    ax[i-1].axhline(0, linestyle='--', color='blue', linewidth=.5, alpha=.35) # horizontal lines


    handles, labels = ax[i-1].get_legend_handles_labels()
    # create the legend again skipping this first entry
    leg = ax[i-1].legend(handles[1:], labels[1:])

    ax2=ax[i-1]
    ax2 = ax[i-1].twinx()
    ax2.grid(False)
    ax2.set_ylabel("n = {}".format(s[i]), rotation=0, labelpad=25)
    ax2.set_yticks([])
```

[image: Plot with code]

Comment: Why did you delete my yesterday's answer? It included a way to simulate your data. Without data it is very hard to answer this kind of question.

Comment: To draw you quantile lines independent of `height`, use `vlines` instead of `axvline`: `p1.vlines(quatrilesx_data[k], ymin=0, ymax=data_y_data[find_nearest(data_x_data, quatrilesx_data[k])], ...)`

Comment: I think you need `ymin, ymax = ax[i-1].set_ylim(); ax[i-1].set_ylim(-0.5, max(1, ymax))`. A kde plot can be a lot larger than 1. A kde plot of height 4 wouldn't fit even if you modify the subplot dimensions. The height of the kde depends on how much of the data is concentrated in a narrow region on the x-axis. When the region is more narrow, the heigth has to go up in order to keep a total area of 1.

Comment: @gerihuber, please provide some data otherwise it's super difficult to try or to troubleshoot. And if another user has kindly provided a solution for you.. it would be great to acknowledge it, instead of just posting another question

Comment: @gerihuber Are your questions solved via the comments? Or are there still things unclear?

Comment: @JohanC Thank you so much, it worked perfectly!!